# The need of database.savepoint vs not using try catch at all

Tags: apex, trigger, transaction

This has been something that has been really bugging me. What is the need of using using a database.setsavepoint along with try catch when you can just do without it?

With try catch and savepoint.

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
try
{
    insert someRecords;
    delete someOtherRecords;
    update anotherRecord;
}
catch (Exception pokemon)
{
    Database.rollback(sp);
}
```

Without try catch and savepoint

```
insert someRecords;
delete someOtherRecords;
update anotherRecord;
```

Let's say you have requirement where any error with any of the three DML should just prevent all execution, then the way I see it the second approach is as good as the first but only the first one seems to be unnecessarily complicating it. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### tl;dr

Don't allow exceptions to reach the top of the stack except in controlled situations. They almost never do what you want them to do. The first option is useful for controllers, but is less acceptable in other places. The second option you present should never be used, with one exception (pun intended). Less code is not always more desirable.

---

The latter option is (almost always) a bad idea. An uncaught exception can have negative consequences. Different contexts have different preferred solutions.

## Triggers

Always prefer partial updates, and report errors to the parent record with addError. As a simple example:

```
Map<Id, Account> parents = new Map<Id, Account>();
Map<Id, String> errors = new Map<Id, String>();
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
  // Pretend we're doing something interesting here
  parents.put(record.AccountId, new Account());
}
Account[] updates = parents.values();
Database.SaveResult results = Database.update(updates, false);
for(Integer index = 0; index < updates.size(); index++) {
  if(!results[index].isSuccess()) {
    errors.put(updates[index].Id, results[index].getError()[0].getMessage());
  }
}
for(Contact record: Trigger.new) {
  if(errors.get(record.AccountId) != null) {
    record.addError('Failed to save related data. First error was: '+errors.get(record.AccountId));
  }
}
```

This is a lot longer than you might expect for a simple update, but it allows partial updates to succeed in bulk. You can codify this into a framework, such as fflib's unit of work.

## Visualforce Controllers

Always use the try-catch-rollback design. If you don't, and an uncaught exception makes it to the top of the stack, the user will lose all their work on the Visualforce "white screen of death" page. This means they'll have to start over from the last saved data.

## Invocable Methods/Apex REST/web services

Always prefer to try-catch-rollback so you have better control over the error messages, and particularly for flows, which may run effectively in parallel, and a single uncaught exception in a Flow context can cause all parallel flows to automatically fail.

## Aura/Lightning

Always prefer to try-catch-rethrow `AuraHandledException`. While any exception technically works, catching any other Exception and rethrowing `AuraHandledException` is the documented method, and by far, more stable in the error body format than other exception types. Notably, a `DmlException` returns a completely different structure you'll have to be prepared for in comparison to `AuraHandledException`.

## Unit Tests

Here, I'm actually going to say that the latter method is acceptable. You shouldn't try-catch for unexpected exceptions, and unit tests rollback anyways, so in your unit test code, you can save some time and lines of code by intentionally not catching exceptions. Any uncaught exception fails the test, which is ideal. Your unit tests should only ever use try-catch if it expects to get an exception.

## Asynchronous Code and Other Contexts

In some cases, you may want to throw exceptions to get logs, and other times you might want to be more in control so you can log errors directly. I prefer to log my errors so I can control the notifications, but this is an area that is more of an opinion-based topic. The other areas have more objective reasoning as to why a certain technique is preferred.

---

Outside of this specific advice, I always recommend using try-catch as little as possible. Use guard statements to avoid exceptions when possible (e.g. checking for a value of zero before trying to divide), and keep try-catch statements areas as little as possible. Every line of code that shouldn't possibly throw an exception shouldn't be guarded by a try-catch. This will make logic bugs much easier to hunt down in many cases. My average try-catch blocks are only a few lines long, and many of the classes I write don't use try-catch at all, but rather handle errors in more appropriate ways.

Comment: N.B. while the fflib UnitOfWork pattern does implement wrapping multiple DML operations within a savepoint; it does not support partial success OOTB (i.e. allorNothing=false). You have to delegate to an IDoWork handler for partial success operations and then it still is complicated when you have a batch of inter-related object DML in the Unit of work. I guess what I'm saying is that fflib provides no magic bullet for handling partial rollbacks in an allOrNothing = false use case